# What are the minimum permissions to show the Craft debug toolbar?

Tags: craft3, permissions, debugging

To help validate a process is in place, we would like to allow a tester to login and view the Craft debug toolbar to see the logs.  Currently, we have given the tester Admin, but we would like to only provide the minimum permissions to view the toolbar.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The debug toolbar is available to Admin users only, see https://craftcms.com/features/all#debug-toolbar

There's no way of customising this, the line of code that enforces it can be seen at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/a859f09df6d90bfa92ca1818418eab508c0e82df/src/web/Application.php#L405